# Inserting a record in PL/SQL block using for loop is yielding error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am creating a table of inetegers called 'integer_properties' from 1 to 1000 the table columns are:

```
integer,isPrime,isOdd,isEven,digitCount;
```

I want to insert records using a for loop i tried following but the error says: 'missing SELECT keyword'

```
BEGIN
   for k in 1..1000
   loop
      insert into integer_properties(integer,
                                     isPrime,
                                     isEven,
                                     isOdd,
                                     digitCount)
         values(k,null,null,null,null);
   end loop;
END;
```

It is tedious to enter 1000 numbers with DDL command without using PL/SQL block. I am trying to enter the loop variable values in the integer column. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in a single query.

```
insert into integer_properties
select level, null, null, null, null
from dual
connect by level <= 1000;

commit;
```

[LEVEL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns001.htm) is a pseudocolumn used in hierarchical queries.

Your code seems fine, but using [INTEGER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i54335) as column name <strike>might be</strike> is causing problem. If you enclose it in double quotes, it will work fine. So, better to avoid using keywords while naming columns.